# JPQL keep throwing The expression is not a valid conditional expression

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql, apache-tomee

I've reached dead end with this. I keep getting:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT a FROM UserEntity u JOIN u.addresses a WHERE u.email =: email]. 
[52, 69] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1585)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

My entities:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS", schema = "Test")
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address_name")
    private String addressName;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address_content")
    private String addressContent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity user;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", schema = "Test")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<AddressEntity> addresses;

}
```

My DAO:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM UserEntity u JOIN u.addresses a WHERE u.email =: email");
        query.setParameter("email", email);
        return query.getResultList();
```

I have no idea what's wrong. I've already tried it with allArgsConstructor and also tried to fetch it from the AddressEntity.

I'm using TomEE plume 7.0.3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution:

```
SELECT a FROM UserEntity u JOIN u.addresses a WHERE u.email =: email
```

Should be as:

```
SELECT a FROM UserEntity u JOIN u.addresses a WHERE u.email = :email
```

Comment: just to highlight what was fixed: there should be no space in between the colon and your named parameter